# BigQuery _TABLE_SUFFIX for ga_sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

This query works fine...

```
SELECT page.* FROM `zentinel-datawarehouse.xxx.ga_sessions_20170601` ga,
UNNEST (hits) hits,
UNNEST (hits.page) page
```

but when i need use _table_suffix

```
SELECT page.* FROM `zentinel-datawarehouse.xxx.ga_sessions_*` ga,
UNNEST (hits) hits,
UNNEST (hits.page) page
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX>=20170601
```

Dont works any more...

This happened in thats date because hits.page is record repeteabled... in month 08 or 09 works fine because is record NULL
ANY IDEA???

REGARDS

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what you mean? any error message?

Comment: ERROR:Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<pagePath STRING, hostname STRING, pageTitle STRING, ...> at [3:9]

Comment: I test this with use only two digits for the table suffix and works....

Comment: then I think some tables have different schema, try to locate when was the schema change applied it might be that jan-feb has one schema, and since march updated schema

Comment: Yes, the schame change 20170703  hits.page record repeteable to record null....and the query not works in the oldest schema

Answer (score 1):

if you get the below error message

> ERROR:Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains
>   expression of type STRUCT at [3:9]

I think some tables have different schema, try to locate when was the schema change applied it might be that jan-feb has one schema, and since march updated schema.

With Google Analytics  export you encounter this schema change frequently.

What you can do here, is that you patch your tables, eg: fix the schema in a direction that will help you.
Without doing the fix, you would need to have two different queries to target both schema(s) (and more schemas will follow if the GA team changes on the go).

You should have a script that constantly propagates to previous tables all the schema changes they introduce with newer updates.

Comment: Agreed. I've run into schema differences breaking wildcard queries before. I worked around it by copying the tables with like schemas to a new dataset so the wildcard only covers those tables.

Answer (score 0):

`hits.page` is not an array but a struct. You're already cross joining "hits" (which is an array), that should be sufficient.
You can only cross join arrays or tables. You want to remove this statement as it only work if hits.page is null:

```
SELECT
  page.*
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_201712*` t, t.hits h
LIMIT
  1000
```